# Is it common behaviour for loop to ignore IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate over a class with __getitem__ *,* __len__.
Sometimes the getitem might give a indexerror, but no exception is shown in the output. The program does not stop, only the loop breaks.

But When I access the items individually I do get the indexerror.

My question is why am I not getting the indexerror in forloop case.

Class Definition

```
class Abc:                          
    a = [1,2,3,4]                   

    def __len__(self):              
        return 4                    

    def __getitem__(self,index):    
        if(index==2):               
            raise IndexError        
        return self.a[index]
```

Code-1

```
foo = Abc()                         

for y in foo:                       
    print(y)                        

print("The End")
```

Output For Code-1

```
1
2
The End
```

Code 2

```
foo = Abc()

print(foo[1])
print(foo[2])
```

Output For Code 2:

```
2
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>                                  
    foo[2]                          
  File "test.py", line 9, in __getitem__                                
    raise IndexError                
IndexError
```

`test.py was filename`

Note : The first comment answers the question.

Comment: "Note for loops expect that an IndexError will be raised for illegal indexes to allow proper detection of the end of the sequence." - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__